# Disabling ViewController in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

How would I disable a user from interacting with any elements in the view controller while downloading data for that view?

```
onStartParse()
fetchUserInfo()
onFinishedParse()
```

I have these 3 methods in my `viewDidLoad`. The `fetchUserInfo()` is the method which actually does the downloading from my database

Comment: `controller.view.userInteractionEnabled = false`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disabling user interaction of the current view on screen](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7878022/disabling-user-interaction-of-the-current-view-on-screen)

Comment: You can set `userInteractionEnabled` to `false` when you stat downloading. When the download ends, set `userInteractionEnabled` back to `true`. Look at the linked duplicate if you would like to disable interaction temporarily in the entire app.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable User Interaction with a ViewController temporarily](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15948251/disable-user-interaction-with-a-viewcontroller-temporarily)

Comment: buttons are still able to be pressed during download

Comment: Add a transparent view on `self.view` and set its `userInteraction = NO`. Remove this after downloading.

Answer (score 8):

Write the below function on start downloading and on complete downloading in swift

```
func onStartDownloading(){
self.view.userInteractionEnabled = false

}

func onCompleteDownloading(){

self.view.userInteractionEnabled = true
}
```

Comment: I tried this but buttons are still pressable and bring about their respective actions

Comment: Do you have buttons on navigation bar or at TabBar , it is possible if the button are the part of superview?

Comment: None of the UIElements are being disabled, whether on the view or in the navigation bar